# Trying to check if there is user input

Tags: c#, c++, string, character

I am reading the book thinking like a programmer. However everything is done in c++ and I am doing the exercises in C#. I am having trouble converting a section to c#. I will post the question, the book's c++ code and my attempt in c#. The if statement is empty, I have tried originally to take in with Readline then converting to char and now switched to reading it as a string then convert to a char.

PROBLEM: READING A NUMBER WITH THREE OR
FOUR DIGITS, FURTHER SIMPLIFIED

Write a program to read a number character by character and convert it to an integer, using just one char variable and two int variables. The number will have either three or four digits.

```
cout << "Enter a three-digit or four-digit number: ";
char digitChar = cin.get();
 int threeDigitNumber = (digitChar - '0') * 100;
 int fourDigitNumber = (digitChar - '0') * 1000;
digitChar = cin.get();
threeDigitNumber += (digitChar - '0') * 10;
fourDigitNumber += (digitChar - '0') * 100;
digitChar = cin.get();
threeDigitNumber += (digitChar - '0');
fourDigitNumber += (digitChar - '0') * 10;
digitChar = cin.get();
if (digitChar == 10) {
cout << "Numbered entered: " << threeDigitNumber << "\n";
} else {
fourDigitNumber += (digitChar - '0');
cout << "Numbered entered: " << fourDigitNumber << "\n";
}
```

My code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter in your 3 or 4 digit number");
            string stringDigit = Console.ReadLine();

            char charDigit = char.Parse(stringDigit);


            //convert the char to an int and the correct place value
            int threeDigitNumber = (charDigit - '0') * 100; 
            int fourDigitNumber = (charDigit - '0') * 1000;

            stringDigit = Console.ReadLine();
            charDigit = char.Parse(stringDigit);

            threeDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0') * 10;
             fourDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0') * 100;

            stringDigit = Console.ReadLine();
            charDigit = char.Parse(stringDigit);

            threeDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0');
            fourDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0') * 10;

            stringDigit = Console.ReadLine();
            charDigit = char.Parse(stringDigit);

            //check if the number is a 3 or 4 digit number
            if ()//unsure what to check
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbered entered is: " + threeDigitNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                fourDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0');
                Console.WriteLine("Numbered entered is: " + fourDigitNumber);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a close equivalent would be more like this:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in your 3 or 4 digit number");

            char charDigit = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;


            //convert the char to an int and the correct place value
            int threeDigitNumber = (charDigit - '0') * 100;
            int fourDigitNumber = (charDigit - '0') * 1000;

            charDigit = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

            threeDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0') * 10;
            fourDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0') * 100;

            charDigit = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

            threeDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0');
            fourDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0') * 10;

            charDigit = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

            //check if the number is a 3 or 4 digit number
            if (charDigit == '\r') //you get a CR character on Enter
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbered entered is: " + threeDigitNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                fourDigitNumber += (charDigit - '0');
                Console.WriteLine("Numbered entered is: " + fourDigitNumber);
            }
```

Because `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` is getting a single character for you. In your code you are reading the entire line.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was under the impression that the "." operator was used to access methods and properties of the class. I don't see `KeyChar` as a property of Console

Comment: ReadKey() is the method, and it returns a "ConsoleKeyInfo" struct as a result. That struct in turn has a "KeyChar" property that you can access with the "."